# Calling ServerSide Method using Jquery in .Net1.1

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using .net1.1 and trying to call a server side method using Jquery on click of browser Close button.My code is not working.I am posting my code below.Will anybody Guide me where did i go wrong?

```
<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout" onbeforeunload="javascript:return test()" >

Ceci est une page cachée. Elle est utilisée pour la gestion du multi-fenétrage.

</body>


    function test()
    {
       debugger;
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HiddenPage.aspx/GetServerTime",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("success"); 
        },
        error: function(msg) {
        alert("Error! Try again..."); 
         }
            });


                return false;           
                        })

        }
```

In Code behind

==================

```
[WebMethod()]


public DateTime GetServerTime()
{


return DateTime.Now;
}
```

}

The control does not go to this web method,I am not able to debug,COntrol goes to '   $(document).ready(function() ' after that whole block runs.It is not showing any type of error,but alerts are not showing.If I use any other return type instead of DateTime,It is still not working

**When I am Calling this method test on onload,It is showing alert of error Conditon.But I have to call it when broswer is closed.In any Case it is not going to web method.

Comment: What's happening in debug ? Do you enter your WebMethod ? If not, you've got an url problem.

Comment: What is the problem with URL?I have written web method in code behind.

Comment: Just asking if you enter your WebMethod in debug : do you, don't you ?

Comment: No.i am not able to debug the web method

Comment: And did you try to debug the javascript with firebug, for example ? To see if you enter your javascript method, or if you get any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot specifically check for a browser close. Using `onbeforeunload` will fire when someone is redirected from this page also.  Try binding your event using jQuery on DOM load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).unload(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        test();
    });
});
```

I can't say exactly why your code doesn't because you haven't provided any error information.

**Calling web method from script**

You need to take a look at your web service, you need to tell it you'll be calling it from script and as the other guy rightly says, you cannot implicitly serialize a `DateTime` so the *laziest* way to get this is to just return a string instead.

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string GetServerTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() { ... })` doesn't execute a function but registers a functoin to be executed when the document is loaded.
`$(document).ready(function() { ... })` register a function for the load event of the document. You register this function in onbeforeunload event, this function will never be executed.  Because when you register the function in onbeforeunload event, the document has already been loaded and is being unloaded. 
If you want to call a method in onbeforeunload , just write the JS code to call WebMethod without `$(document).ready`

```
function test()
{  
    // $(document).ready(function() {  //delete this        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HiddenPage.aspx/GetServerTime",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) { alert("success");    },
    error: function(msg) { alert("Error! Try again..."); }
    });
    return false; 
}
```